# Add filter to st.data_editor

Tags: python, pandas

https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/data/st.data_editor

Quiero usar st.data_editor para dar la posibilidad usar checkboxes en el dataframe, pero una vez le agrego la funcion filter se borran los cambios hechos en el dataframe.

https://blog.streamlit.io/auto-generate-a-dataframe-filtering-ui-in-streamlit-with-filter_dataframe/

Un ejemplo:

```
def filter_dataframe(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # El mismo codigo del blog "filter dataframe"
    return df



def crearModDF():
    try: 
        df_edited = st.data_editor(df, num_rows="dynamic")
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_edited)
    except:
        df = pd.DataFrame(
            [
                {"command": "st.selectbox", "rating": 4, "is_widget": True},
                {"command": "st.balloons", "rating": 5, "is_widget": False},
                {"command": "st.time_input", "rating": 3, "is_widget": True},
            ]
        )
    return filter_dataframe(df)


def modificarDF(df):

    df_edited = st.data_editor(df, num_rows="dynamic")
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_edited)
    return df

df = modificarDF(crearModDF())


df

favorite_command = df.loc[df["rating"].idxmax()]["command"]
st.markdown(f"Your favorite command is **{favorite_command}** ")
```